# Should I create DTO to remove id from object in put method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I wanna create simple API, for example - `todo` API.

Created model

```
public class Todo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Completed { get; set; }
}
```

And than in code, I wanna create some methods. So I go to put method, start writing:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public IActionResult Put(Todo todo, int id)
{
    ...
}
```

And than I don't know if I should check if id from URL is same as id from `todo` or I should ignore id from `todo` or create `TodoUpdateDTO` without `id`.

I know what whatever I would do - it will just work, but what is a good practice in .NET Core?

Comment: [remember, when designing your #WebAPI, your data model is not your object model is not your resource model is not your message model #API360](https://twitter.com/mamund/status/767212233759657984?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E767212233759657984%7Ctwgr%5E%7Ctwcon%5Es1_&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fcodeopinion.com%2Fweb-api-resource-model-isnt-data-model%2F) . [This](https://codeopinion.com/web-api-resource-model-isnt-data-model/) article goes into greater detail, explaining why the resource and data model often need to be separate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would keep the `id` in my method, so what you have written here seems correct:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public IActionResult Put(int id)
{
...
}
```

However regarding your class, I would usually use two classes like this:

```
public class TodoBase
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Completed { get; set; }
}
```

And:

```
public class Todo: TodoBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

So it would be better, in some methods like `Put`, you use the `TodoBase` class:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public IActionResult Put(int id, [FromBody]TodoBase todo)
{
...
}
```

So in case you want to create a new entity in which it's `Id` is auto generated, you don't have to provide the `Id` in your request anymore and you can simply use the base class, but for methods like `Get`, you can use the `Todo` class as it will be retrieved from the db and it should contains `Id` already.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a separate `PutTodoRequest` class for the `HttpPut`, just because I might need to add validation logic for the request payload.

```
public class PutDotoRequest
{
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public bool? Completed { get; set; }
}

[HttpPut("{id}")]
public IActionResult Put([FromBody] PutDotoRequest request)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest();

    // code
}
```